# Redirect to Previous page after FB Login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect

I'm using below function for redirection after **FB login**, But it's redirecting to Customers Account Dashboard, Instead of Account Dashboard I'd like to redirect to Home Page or the Previous Page.

```
 protected function _loginPostRedirect()
 {
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {
        // Set default URL to redirect customer to
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());

    } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
    } else {
        if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
        }
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
}
```

I've tried

> $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getHomeUrl());
>
> $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getCurrentUrl());

But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this to redirect to home page

```
$homeUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
$this->_redirectUrl($homeUrl);
```

To redirect to Previous page

```
$this_redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null);
```

Answer (score 1):

to redirect to home url try to use Url Helper instead of Customer Helper
`Mage::helper('url')->getHomeUrl();`
@see Mage_Core_Helper_Url::getHomeUrl()